# Upload a https-link to a DataStore

Tags: vsphere-client

I have a direct link to a 4GB file.

How can I download it to a DataStore at vSphere 4? (without downloading it to my computer)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need SSH access to the ESX console as ESX/ESXi comes with BusyBox and BusyBox has a slim `wget`. You can enable SSH access from the vSphere Client, in [Configuration > Security > SSH Server](http://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2010/09/15/enabling-ssh-in-vmware-vsphere-4-1-esxi/).

First, SSH to the ESX host (use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) if you're on Windows)

```
$ ssh root@12.34.56.78
```

Change directory to the datastore you want to put the file in

```
~ # cd /vmfs/volumes/datastore1
```

Then ,simply wget the file

```
~ # wget http://example.com/file.iso
```

Now mount/use the file from the vSphere client.

Comment: +1 Thanks it seems to work good - the problem is, the 'wget' don't support SSL

Comment: Ah I see, I'm currently not at my desk, so I can't check if ESXi has cURL or not, or if that's the old ESX. Either way, you can always try it by doing `~ # curl http://example.com/file.iso -o file.iso`

Answer (score 1):

He asked about HTTPS link, not HTTP.

HTTPS links cause this error: 
*wget: not an http or ftp url*

Solution: 
Compile own wget, with SSL support, 
or download curl binary (static compiled) for ESX.